# How to get IP address and port number of IIS-hosted website using its process id?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, pid

I want to be able to find out IP address and port number of the website, which **my code is running behind**; and I don't have access to **HttpContext or any request information** *( The reason is that I wanna do this from another library which will be called from the api controller. and for some security reasons, I don't want to pass any request information or any additional information to this function )* . I figured out that I can access IP address and the port number of current website using website process id and also with the help of **netstat** command. So Here is my code for getting the process id of my website:

```
int processId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
```

Let's say this give me this number as my website process id: 32351. But the problem is, all of IIS hosted websites are running behind **pid number 4** which is the process id of **System**.
below is the result of **netstat -ano** command for the IIS websites:

[image: open this link]

Do you have any suggestions for my problem or any other ways for getting IP address and port number of the current website?

Comment: You'd better explain why "I don't have access to HttpContext or any request information". Your code can access `Process` class, then all other classes are also available.

Comment: from where you want to find this infos ? from inside your web app ? from outside ?

Comment: @LexLi I wanna do this from another library and for some security reasons, I don't want to pass any request information or any additional information to this function.

Comment: @Aristos As I mentioned above, from another library which will be called from my controller

Comment: That library can use `HttpContext.Current` to access whatever it might need, and you should know that you have no control on that. Then back to my original comment, why do you fight in vain?

Comment: @Kingfish if you do not have some clue, then you need to make a scan

Comment: @LexLi HttpContext.Current can be used when the request thread and the current thread are the same. sometimes they are not on the same thread which leads to HttpContext.Current being null